# Cumulative score statistics

Tags: discussion, statistics, score

What is grand total score (sum of all points) for

1. users (sum of all reputation points for all users)
2. questions (sum of all votes for all questions)
3. answers (sum of all votes for all answers)

Is there numbers or plot somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

There are current stats for all stack exchange sites available here:  https://stackexchange.com/sites

This doesn't plot the value over time, however choosing ["more stats"](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true) will show you some trend data.

Comment: No total number of votes up/down there. Neither there is average rep/score.

Comment: @Vi neither of which you asked for...

Comment: I asked for sum of all {questions,answers} votes and sum of all user rep.

Comment: @Vi, if that is what you meant to ask your questions, I would suggest editing it, because that is not what I thought you were after when I read your question.